# GRUB boot error rescue

Tags: linux, windows-10, grub, grub2

Recently created a Linux/windows 10 dual boot and something went wrong.... every time i boot up my PC it brings me straight to GRUB rescue and i am unable to type or access the BIOS menu (i have tried the hot keys don't work). My CD drive doesn't work so i have a boot-able USB with windows 10 set up on it but obviously cant access BIOS to select that.

Error message i receive on boot is:

```
error: no such device: 18a41c71-6205-42f3-be31-ele196f9b57d. 
entering rescue mode.... 
grub rescue> _
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Accessing BIOS happens before GRUB takes over so if you can´t access BIOS there is some other reason then GRUB for that.

Comment: This [Howtoforge](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/repair-linux-boot-with-grub-rescue/) article might help you out here.

Comment: Welcome, format source code and program output as code block with `Ctrl+K` please.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your BIOS supports a "fast boot" option that skips the part of the boot process where you can enter the bios (usually `esc` or `F2`) or activate the boot menu (usually `F12`). When the computer is powered off. Try holding down the power button until the computer beeps three times. I know this sounds like voodoo, but this is how I can disable "fast boot" for my intel board and choose the boot menu by pressing `F12`.

Comment: i think i may of set it to ultra boot which could be why i am unable to access BIOS so would re-seting the CMOS fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried (while the computer is switched off) to hold down the power button until the computer beeps three times?

Comment: For my intel board this temporarily disables fast boot.

Comment: I am sure that if "fast boot" or "ultra boot" is to blame, your mainboard manufacturer offers a solution to get into the bios without resetting the CMOS! Consult the manual of your mainboard.

Answer (score 0):

Some laptops (new) come with an external switch for entering boot menu . Do check if ur laptop is having or not.. if not then hold power button until u hear three beeps. And there u go .. recover windows 10 by a live USB or DVD. In that case. Use cmd. There are some videos on youtube regarding recovery of bootloader but first of all disable this fast boot or enter boot menu